# mapbox: как получить координаты центра Long / Lat если имеются только bbox координаты

Tags: javascript, mapbox

Мне нужно воспользоваться функцией `map.toFly()` чтобы при нажатии кнопки на карте перемещаться из первого места назначения во второе.

Согласно документации Mapbox (https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/flyto/), аргументом этой функции служит объект со свойством - `center`, представляющий  массив с центральными координатами `long / lat`  пункта назначения.

Например,  `map.flyTo({ center: [10.39170933059438, 63.4309997568285])`

Моя проблема с реализацией этого метода состоит в том, что не для первого, не для второго мест назначения у меня нет центральных координат `long / lat`. Имеются только `bbox` координаты для каждого из 2х мест. То есть я не могу написать что-то вроде: `map.flyTo (bbox)`

Вопрос: как получить координаты центра `Long/Lat` для каждого из местоположений на основе  `bbox` координат?

Answer (score 1):

Для этого есть специальный метод

[map.fitBounds()](https://docs.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/example/fitbounds/)

bbox задается 2мя точками (диагональю)

```
  map.fitBounds([[
    32.958984, -5.353521
  ], [
    43.50585, 5.615985
  ]]);
```

Вот пример кода, нажмите на кнопку, чтобы переместиться к bbox

```html
<script src='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.js'></script>
<link href='https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.53.1/mapbox-gl.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<div id='map'></div>
<button id='fit'>map.fitBounds()</button>
<style>
#fit {
  position: relative;
}
body {
  margin:0; 
}
#map { 
  position:absolute; 
  top:0;
  bottom:0; 
  width:100%; 
}
</style>
<script>
let map = new mapboxgl.Map({
    container: 'map', 
    style: {
        "version": 8,
        "sources": {
            "simple-tiles": {
                "type": "raster",
                "tiles": [
                    "https://a.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png",
                    "https://b.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png"
                ],
                "tileSize": 256
            }
        },
        "layers": [{
            "id": "simple-tiles",
            "type": "raster",
            "source": "simple-tiles",
            "minzoom": 0,
            "maxzoom": 22
        }]
    },
    center: [30.3, 60], 
    zoom: 12 
});

document.querySelector('button').onclick = function(){
  map.fitBounds([[
    32.958984, -5.353521
  ], [
    43.50585, 5.615985
  ]]);
}
</script>
```